# I can't access the value of the array in state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

**Problem:** I have a state. And I want to reach the value in this state. But the value in the array.

---

```
  state = {
    base: [ {tomato: false}, {egg: false} ],
    contents: [
      {mushroom: false},
      {olive: false},
      {greenPepper: false},
      {sausage: false},
      {tomato: false},
      {redPapper: false}
    ]
  };
```

---

```
class Preivew extends React.Component{
  state = {
    base: this.props.contents.base  
  };

  getBase = () => {
    return(
      this.state.base.map( (value) => {
        console.log(value)
      } )
    )
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
      <Wrap>
        <div className={classes.imageBox}>
          <div className={classes.image}>
          {console.log(this.getBase())} 
          </div>
        </div>
      </Wrap>
    )
  } 
};
```

**output:**

> {tomato: false}
>
> {egg: false}

**I want to reach "false" here. Because I'm going to do check operations with "if else".**

Comment: Is this your expected output? What are you trying to get.

Comment: @Kevin.a  I want to reach "false" here. Because I'm going to do check operations with "if else".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Object.values`.

```
getBase = () => this.state.base.map(value => Object.values(value)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first element of `Object.values()`

```
getBase = () => {
    return(
      this.state.base.map( (value) => {
        console.log(Object.values(value)[0])
      } )
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.state.base.map( (value) => {
    Object.keys(value).forEach(key => {
        console.log(value[key])
    })
}
```

You can solve this using Object.keys in combination with forEach.

Answer (score 0):

Update this property

```
 getBase = (ingredient) => {
        const ingPresent = this.state.base.find(value => value[ingredient] != undefined);
        return ingPresent ? ingPresent[ingredient] : false;
    };
```

And in the render

```
render(){
    {this.getBase('tomato') && (
        <p>Hello tomato present</p>
    )}
}
```

The function also handles the case when the base array doesn't contain the ingredient